# Making a table cell not clickable with JQuery in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Should not be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr>
     <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
     <th>Content that should be clickable</th>
     <th>Content that should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But much larger.

Then I have this jquery:

```
$('.table > tbody > tr').click(function() {

//Things happens

});
```

I want to never trigger the jQuery when I click on the checkbox, but trigger the JQuery when I click on the row (tr).

Right now it always triggers the JQuery, even when I just click on the check box.

Any help?

Comment: @besciualex There are 3 answers that work. I will just upvote those who worked and select the one that I will use.Thanks.

Comment: I agree. But if they work, that doesn't mean they are using the best practice. Please keep this in mind all the time. stopProgapagation of an event in your case works, but is not a recommended practice. Read more here https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: you can put click handler for checkbox inside th or td and return without doing anything. use `stopPropagation`

```js
$(function(){
  $('table > tbody > tr input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});

$('table > tbody > tr').click(function() {
   alert("row clicked");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Should not be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr>
     <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
     <th>Content that should be clickable</th>
     <th>Content that should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should update your jquery to:

```
$('table tr th:not(.not-clickable), table tr td:not(.not-clickable)').on('click', function() {
    //Things happens 
});
```

By doing this, you tell jQuery to execute the click function, for all cells, except the ones who have class 'not-clickable'.

Then you update the html code, and add 'not-clickable' class to the cell you want to skip the click function.

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class='not-clickable'>Should not be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td class='not-clickable'><input type="checkbox"></td>
     <td>Content that should be clickable</td>
     <td>Content that should be clickable</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Also I noticed you were using **th** instead of **td** in table body. It works because browsers are smart, but is not a good practice to put **th** in **tbody**. Is not W3C compliant.

Here is a fully working snippet:

```js
$('table tr th:not(.not-clickable), table tr td:not(.not-clickable)').on('click', function() {
    //Things happens 
    alert('Yeey! Is clickable');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border='1'>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class='not-clickable'>Should not be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td class='not-clickable'><input type="checkbox"></td>
     <td>Content that should be clickable</td>
     <td>Content that should be clickable</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the target form the event if it is a checkbox

```js
$(function() {
  $('.table > tbody > tr').click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is(':checkbox')) {
        console.log('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='table'>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Should not be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr>
     <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
     <th>Content that should be clickable</th>
     <th>Content that should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (if you need to avoid click on the the checkbox)

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false;">
```

Otherwise you can use the **disabled** attribute in the checkbox.

Basically it depends on your needs. Should the user be able to click the checkbox somehow or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
$('table tr th:not([not-clickable])').click(function() {
  alert("Things happens");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th not-clickable>Should not be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
    <th>Should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr>
     <th not-clickable><input type="checkbox"></th>
     <th>Content that should be clickable</th>
     <th>Content that should be clickable</th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```